# Change appName and logo for a published app in Microsoft teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service, microsoft-appstudio

I would like to change the app name and logo for a published app in Microsoft teams.

Do the users need to reinstall the app when appName and logo are changed in app-studio?
and do the users need to reinstall the app when appName and logo are changed in the azure app directory and bot services?

Comment: To change your App-Name or App-Logo users need to uninstall previous app and need to re-install again for the changes.

Comment: If you are trying on store apps then just user need to update. Or if your trying on test apps then in that case user need to reinstall app to get changes applicable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying on store apps then just user need to update. Or if your trying on test apps then in that case user need to reinstall app to get changes applicable.

Comment: Hey, Thank you. One more doubt in the case of test apps we have to make a change in the azure directory or app studio manifest in the team's app. My changes are not getting reflected.

Comment: Hey, is there a way to change the bot handle name in azure bot services?